# Are there any Star Trek episodes in which the bad guys looked human and the good guys looked very alien?

Tags: star-trek

My recollection is that in *Star Trek*, physical appearance is often a clue about the character — I heard about "Red Shirts" years before the Internet and the deep exploration of *Star Trek* lore that it allowed.

It seems to me that in every case I can remember, if there were two alien species in opposition, the species that looked human were the ones the Federation, or at least the crew of the Enterprise, aligned themselves with.

But was there an exception to this, where the bad guys looked human but the Enterprise's crew looked deeper than this?

Comment: Would this have been a _TOS_ or _TNG_ episode? And can you elaborate on what you mean by _"the Enterprise's crew looked deeper than this"_?

Comment: @LogicDictates: anywhere in ST universe. By Enterprise's crew I mean basically the Federation or the local representatives thereof.

Comment: From the title, I thought you were looking for the title of a specific episode that you'd seen. Are you actually just looking for any episode that fits this template, rather than one episode in particular?

Comment: @LogicDictates: yes, any episode and the answer provided by Andrew sounds like an episode which is specifically about this idea.

Comment: The *Voyager* two-parter Equinox involves another federation crew and an attacking non corporeal alien force, in which the Federation crew are the baddies.

Comment: In TOS "Devil in the Dark", the very alien-looking Horta turns out to be (more or less) a "good guy", and the Starfleet station personnel themselves kind of look like jerks.

Comment: @JohnGordon I believe the Horta called them "Murderers! Assassins!" and accused them of infanticide and genocide, so yes "kind of look like jerks" is the right direction. https://youtu.be/jyKiXLYAajg

Comment: @JohnGordon That's an answer, not just a comment. Please convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Voyager episode [Nemesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) fits:

> Chakotay's shuttle has been shot down, leaving him stranded alone on a
> jungle planet. **He is captured by troops of the humanoid Vori species,**
> led by Brone (Michael Mahonen), but they appear to release him when
> they determine he is not of the "nemesis". Chakotay and a Vori look
> for his shuttle the next day and encounter two of the "nemesis". **They
> are known as the Kradin, who are fierce, monstrous-looking, and
> technologically-advanced humanoids.**

> The Kradin explain that they are battling a relentless force called
> the Vori, whom they also refer to as "nemesis". Tuvok goes down to the
> planet and rescues Chakotay, who has actually been experiencing an
> elaborate training and brainwashing program to turn him into a Vori
> foot soldier. **He has been thoroughly indoctrinated to believe the
> Kradin are monsters and is disgusted by the sight of them.** Once
> Chakotay is back on Voyager, he is presented with evidence that the
> Kradin are not necessarily the hateful monsters he thought them to be,
> as Captain Janeway confesses to uncertainty concerning the right and
> wrong of the conflict, and that **it was in fact the Kradin who helped
> locate the commander and return him to Voyager.**

The kidnapping/brainwashing [Vori](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vori) look like this

[image: Vori male]

The [Kradin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kradin) who returned Chakotay to his ship look like this [image]

Comment: Somehow I remember that the Kradin didn't *actually* look the way Chakotay saw them -- their inhuman appearance turned out to be a result of the simulation/conditioning. But maybe I'm misremembering?

Comment: I think you're misremembering slightly - they look pretty bad, but Chakotay sees them as looking even worse.

Comment: @ruakh You are thinking of when Tuvok goes to rescue Chakotay but Chakotay sees Tuvok like a Kradin for a short period. The Kradin actually looked like that.

Comment: @thaimin: Yes, I think you're right -- I've rewatched that episode now, and the scene with Tuvok seems to imply that the Kradin don't actually look like that (because why else would the Vori need to brainwash Chakotay into hallucinating that they do?), which must be why I thought that; but indeed, whenever we actually see them, they *do* look like that. So confusing!

Comment: @ruakh To quote the doctor: "I'd say they had you so mixed up they could have convinced you your own mother was a turnip"

Comment: @ruakh: Of course, this is a bit of speculation, but the way the Vori conditioned their soldiers, it would seem reasonable for them to remove any "grey area" between the good and evil that they present the Vori and Kradin as, respectively. In that sense, it would be a desirable outcome if the soldier were to perceive anyone who is not a loyal supporter of the Vori as a Kradin = enemy, no matter whether they are actually part of the Kradin military, Kradin civilians, or a 3rd party who tries to interfere with the conflict in any way.

Answer (score 3):

- [TNG, "Home Soil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Soil): the good guys are a sentient mineral life form. The bad guys are the Federation themselves, who are destroying the mineral life in the process of terraforming their world...unknowingly, but with some degree of willfully ignoring the evidence that the mineral life exists. In the end, Picard negotiates an agreement with the natives to put their planet under quarantine.
- [Voyager, "Scorpion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)): the good guys are a non-humanoid lifeform from another universe with drastically different properties, who are defending themselves from the mostly-humanoid Borg, a particularly attractive example of such being chosen as representative to the Voyager crew. Janeway allies with the Borg and develops a potent nanite-based weapon against the species they attacked. The two humanoid factions end up in conflict at the end, but the sole surviving Borg (the attractive female human one) ends up becoming a permanent member of the crew.

Comment: It is true that Species 8472 were attacked by the Borg and defending themselves, but I would hesitate to label them "good guys". Their slogan "The weak will perish." was in no way restricted to addressing the Borg. Furthermore, note that the entire reason why Voyager allied themselves with the Borg was that 8472 behaved unconditionally hostile and conveyed, telepathically, that "[8472 are conducting] an invasion. They intend on destroying everything."

Answer (score -6):

In addition to other fine, more specific answer - I'll give a more general, and controvertial answer: Probably about every other episode of Star Trek TNG and Star Trek DS9; and that's because **Star Fleet are bad guys.**

No, I don't mean in the Mirror Universe (which could also serve as somewhat of an answer to your question) - I mean the regular one.

You see, Star Trek as a show is mostly a self-narrative of the United Federation of Planets, or rather of specific crews of ships or bases within Star Fleet. It's true that the show is written by real people on Earth in the 20th century CE, but they are choosing protagonists for their stories and describing them, or self-describing them, as the good guys. Unfortunately, that kind of flies in the face of facts (facts-in-the-universe-of-the-show of course).

I won't go into an entire dissertation of why the UFP is an evil empire, but in a nutshell:

1. Human-supremacist civilization
2. Privileged populations (e.g. on Earth) live lives of luxury and leisure while on most planets people need to work to make a living
3. Huge parts of civilizational activity militarized fully or mostly: Foreign relations & diplomacy, scientific research, interstellar travel
4. Civilian political structure flimsy and of little consequence, exerting no control over the military which effectively holds sovereignty
5. Somewhat expansionistic

Point (5.) is actually the more difficult to demonstrate and argue for, but it's certainly the case if you look at Bajor. Even though supposedly that's not a planet which meets the criteria for entering the federation, it manages to strong-arm the Bajorans into letting it control a choke point for interstellar travel and commerce, by a military governor, with that governor also heavily interfering with Bajoran politics and religion. The Federation acts with the clear intent to take over Bajor, in the practical interstellar sense even if not formally through federation membership (which, recall, means loose subservience to Humanity and Earth).

---

You may want to check out [this article](https://www.cracked.com/blog/5-ways-star-trek-federation-evil-empire) about how the Federation is an evil empire (which not exactly my view, but somewhat close).

Comment: Meta-gaming, deconstruction and fanfic are fun, but they're not the basis for a sensible answer

Comment: @Valorum: I don't know what meta-gaming is; fanfic is not relevant to my answer; and answers can very well be based on critical analysis.

Comment: It's quite enjoyable to pretend that the goodies in old properties are actually the baddies. But it's not actually what was intended by the makers.

Comment: @Valorum: The question makes the implicit assumption that if a Starfleet crew is aligned with some party, then they are the good guys; i.e. that Starfleet are good guys. I believe this answer is useful to OP when considering the question. Whether the authors/showrunners also shared this assumption does not change that fact - and thus IMNSHO doesn't change the validity of this answer. Naturally you can downvote it if you don't believe this view is useful.

Comment: A lot of this is between somewhat and very dubious. "Human supremacist" is a pretty major exaggeration. There's an obvious reason that there are more humans than anyone else in *Star Trek*, and that's budgetary reasons. It is the same reason that most aliens look like people with rubber face masks. But if you want to imagine some kind of consistent in-universe reason for it, you could speculate that humans are among the most populous species.

Comment: There's no argument that Starfleet is somewhat militaristic—somewhat, because war is a small part of what they do. But the notion that they have no civilian oversight is mistaken: their Commander-in-chief is the elected president of the Federation, as with most real-world nations. Some of these presidents are former military officers, some are not. Again, like many Earth nations. In those that have compulsory military service—including, perhaps, the one that you live in?— *every* president, or at least every male president, has been ex-military.

Comment: The notion that only on Earth do people live lives of luxury, while everywhere else people have to work for a living, is probably the most egregious, though, because it flies in the face of numerous explicit statements from throughout the show. For instance, according to Captain Picard, the Federation is positively Communist and post-scarcity as regards basic needs:

Comment: "A lot has changed in the past three hundred years. People are no longer obsessed with the accumulation of things. We've eliminated hunger, want, the need for possessions. We've grown out of our infancy."

Comment: People may work for a living on many of the non-Federation planets that members of the Federation visit, but to be clear, those are *non-Federation planets*. Work within the Federation seems to be limited to buying extreme luxury goods from trade with individuals like Ferengi traders, or working for personal fulfillment (see previous).

Comment: I kind of view this as basically like your Sauron answer. When you wrote that one, I pointed out that the moral dubiousness of some of Tolkien's protagonists did not render Sauron anything less than a murderous dictator and probable Hitler stand-in.

Comment: Here, I will point out that the moral dubiousness of some of the Federation's makeup (conceding militarized exploration and interference with Bajor) still isn't enough to render them anything less than a society that is more equal and has better social support than any in existence today, with membership a lot more voluntary than say, the USA or Soviet Union or Russia or even NATO, which also, by the by, has eliminated starvation, poverty and most disease.

Comment: "[the Federation] manages to strong-arm the Bajorans into letting it control a choke point for interstellar travel and commerce, by a military governor, with that governor also heavily interfering with Bajoran politics and religion" - quote from DS9:1x01: "At the request of the Bajoran provisional government, Starfleet has agreed to establish a Federation presence". Kira doesn't like the idea, but even during her initial rant, she identifies the Bajoran government as the driving force for bringing Starfleet to the Bajoran system. Lastly, the degree to which the "military governor" ...

Comment: ... interferes with Bajoran politics and especially religion is, again, heavily driven by the Bajorans themselves, or, by extension, the wormhole aliens.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Once a foreign power starts intervening, its continued intervention is typically encouraged by local allies, and strongly opposed by opponents of those local factions. The latter would typically be portrayed as extremists, radicals, agents of enemies of the intervening power etc.

Comment: So, is Major Kira considered an extremist, a radical, or an enemy agent? But rather than of her, you may be thinking of the organization The Circle, which was featured in the trilogy at the beginning of DS9's season 2. They were indeed labeled as extremist by Starfleet, so let's look at what they did: Apparently, they wanted *all* non-Bajorans to leave Bajor. This request can arguably be called extreme. Then, they kidnap Kira and prepare for a military-grade assault on DS9. And, as it turns out, it *was* a ploy orchestrated by the Cardassian leadership. Maybe you could outline what ...

Comment: ... effects for Bajor the "intervention" by the Federation has caused, in instances where the activity was not directly driven by Bajor (e.g. like when pushing Sisko into his role as an Emissary of the wormhole aliens, kind of against his will), and that ended up in conflict with what local groups from Bajor were aiming for. IMHO ticking off boxes with mere keywords is not a suitable means to determine who is or is not a "bad guy". Otherwise, my local tennis club would have to be labeled an evil empire, given that it is definitely expansionist (it has a process for admitting new members) ...

Comment: ... and interfers with the internal matters of its members (it requests a membership fee and imposes training times).